# Limit converges when I plug in numbers, but diverges when I leave in terms of variables

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, physics, assumptions, conditional, algebra

I have an expression such as the following

$$\frac{ab+a^2c+bx-acx+2adx-(a-x)\sqrt{b^2+2abc+a^2c^2+4acdx}}{2ax}$$

which describes a physical system that I want to find the limit as $x$ goes to 0. If I simply ask Mathematica to take the limit, I get `DirectedInfinity` with some argument.

However, if I plug in some numbers and instead tell *Mathematica* to take the limit in that case, I get a finite result. One example of this is that if I use $a=10$, $b=5$, and $c=3$, I get that the limit is $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{d}{7}$$

I would like to have an expression for the limit generically when $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $x$ are all positive real numbers.

Comment: You should use `Limit[ expression, Assumptions->{a>0,b>0,c>0,d>0,x>0 }]`, see the documentation of `Limit`: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html

Answer (score 5):

Bulding on my comment.

`Limit` can work with `Assumptions` (see the section *Options* within the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html)).

In this case you should write:

```
Limit[1/(2 a x) (a b + a^2 c + b x - a c x + 
    2 a d x - (a - x) Sqrt[b^2 + 2 a b c + a^2 c^2 + 4 a c d x]), 
 x -> 0, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0, x > 0}]
```

With result:

> ```
> (*(b (b + a (c + d)))/(a (b + a c))*)
> ```